# Recommend web-based data report sites?

Tags: sharepoint, crystal-reports, salesforce

For several years now, I've built up a more-or-less reliable system of emailing static PDFs and Excel files to our non-technical clients.  I'd like to upgrade this process to 2010 technology, preferrably in the form of a website than can both act as a file-server for these reports as well as present the data in html.

After some asking around, I know some services like Sharepoint, SalesForce.com, and Crystal Reports Enterprise would fill these needs, but I haven't heard many people actually recommend any one of these.

Some Details:

1. I'm looking for something cheap/free (what else is new?) that our IT department would be willing to implement.
2. This service will only get about 100-200 visitors/downloads a month.
3. It would only need to be updated once a day.

(If I'm using the wrong terminology, feel free to edit)

#### Edit

Thanks, Brian.  Here's a few answers:

1. Yes, reports will be prepared ahead of time.
2. No search capability is needed (just not that much to search).
3. User access is via name & password and each customer cannot see the other's reports.
4. Accessibility hasn't been a concern so far, but it could be in the future, who knows.
5. No collaboration is needed. I'll be posting the content and IT will be maintaining the whole thing (assuming they agree to it).
6. What do you mean by versioning? I freely admit I'm out of my league here.
7. It's those kind of OS projects I might be looking for.  I'll check them out.

Answer (score 0):

Each technology has pros/cons but it comes down to needing more information from your question.

Are you preparing the reports ahead of time? Do you need need search capability, user access controls, collaboration, accessibility, versioning, is this public facing or private facing, etc...

if you are just hosting files on the web and just need a CMS have you considered one o the many open source projects such as wordpress, joomla, drupal, or any of hte many others.

**Edit:**

It sounds like wordpress would be a good choice for your use case.

Comment: Good questions.  See my Edit for a response.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce is a paid service (unless you are one of non-profit orgs or fall into few other exceptional categories). Paying for 200 user accounts seems like overkill for your business case... You could make some website as frontend and just treat SF as "database with benefits" but that would require access to API (Enterprise Edition) and frankly - you'll lose many SF featres so what's the point then?

There's a very nice Salesforce module that would notify you for example "user X has downloaded pdf Y for first time" or "document Z will expire in 2 weeks" but it's called Salesforce Content and paid extra ;)

I have to agree with Brian - please have a look at any of existing free CMS solutions.